# Filling out paragraph text via urllib?

Tags: python

Say I have a paragraph in a site I am managing and I want a python program to change the contents of that paragraph. Is this plausible with urllib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite possibly; it depends on how the site is designed.

If the site is just a collection of static pages (ie .html files) then you would have to get a copy of the page, modify it, and upload the new version - most likely using sftp or WebDAV.

If the site is running a content management system (like Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, etc) then it gets quite a bit simpler - your script can simply post new page content.

If it is static content maintained through a template system (ie Dreamweaver) then life gets quite a bit nastier again - because any changes you make will not be reflected in the template files, and will likely get overwritten and disappear the next time you update the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to any server-side scripting language, its easy.

Comment: thank you for the reply methyl. i have full control of the website. im running it on my own computer to get a good feel of things. can you point me to beginner-level references i can study? im really a beginner on website design

Comment: Sure. You need to read about POST methods and catching data from post within php.